# 2 column min-height 100% difficulties

Tags: html, css, height

First off let me assure you I've searched and tried so many solutions to this seemingly simple layout without success.

For now I've had to resort to laying it out with `display:table`, but would very much prefer a non-script, pure CSS solution using divs.

What I need is a basic 2-column layout: A sidebar div hugging the top-left and a content wrapper div to the right of the sidebar.

The sidebar will contain 3-4 divs, the content wrapper 1 div.

The kicker is I need the background of the sidebar and content wrapper always to fill 100% height of the viewport - even if there's no content inside the content wrapper div.

If there's content inside the content wrapper div, the background of both the sidebar and content wrapper should expand vertically to fill the viewport.

The fiddle below does exactly this. The problem with this approach (using `position:fixed` on the sidebar) occurs once you start "zooming" on mobile devices. The content will then disappear behind the fixed div.

Any advice on how to best achieve this layout?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mnorup/2Xvdn/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got something quite close to what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/2Xvdn/5/

What I changed:

- added a wrapper having the id *outside* and added the following css to it: `{
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 100%;
  }`
- replaced the css for *sidebar* by `{
  background: yellow;
  width: 230px;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: -9999em;
  padding-bottom: 9999em;
  }`
- removed `min-height` for *contentwrap* and added the following css: `{    margin-bottom: -9999em;
  padding-bottom: 9999em;
  }`

Here are some other approaches to have columns with equal heights: http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/equal-height-columns/ I used the here described *Borders and Negative Margins*, just that I used padding instead of borders.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I had already attempted with a negative margins approach, but I must have done something wrong. This solution does exactly what I'm after...even appears to be working as intended in IE 6/7

Comment: @MNorup, never mind :) This solution (negative margin) is part of the CSS framework YAML (http://www.yaml.de/docs/index.html#yaml-grids) and they found at least one downside of this approach when used in combination with anchors. The link points to the docs where you have to find the headline _Equal Heights Grids_ (sadly they don't have an anchor for it ...)

*EDIT:* They just use this approach for browsers not supporting `display: table`, which are IE6/7, so I don't know if the there written downside applies to the implementation in general.

Comment: never stumbled on YAML before, seems extremely useful. As far as anchoring goes, it won't be an issue on this particular project. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Is this doable for you? [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/2Xvdn/2/)

I just changed a width and floated.

CSS

```
#sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  width: 230px;
  border: 0px solid transparent;
  float: left;
}
#contentwrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  background: blue;
  float: left;
  margin-left:10px;
```

---

OK, see if this is closer. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/2Xvdn/3/)

The container for the text is the container for everything, and as it expands, so will the bar on the left.

Smaller contents so you can see the background - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/2Xvdn/4/)

Comment: This approach works until the content exceeds the 100% height of #sidebar (and body).
At this point, the #sidebar - which is first child of 100% height body - will end at, well, 100% height of the parent (using `min-height` or `height`).

Comment: A possible solution then is to wrap it all in a container. That introduces similar problems tho:

CSS

`#wrap {

  min-height: 100%;

  background: red;
  overflow: auto;
}
#sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  width: 230px;
  border: 0px solid transparent;
  float: left;
}
#contentwrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  background: blue;
  float: left;
  margin-left:10px;
}`

Comment: HTML: `<div id="wrap">
  <div id="sidebar">
    <div id="logo">logo</div>
    <div id="menu">menu</div>
    <div id="footer">footer</div>
  </div><!-- sidebar -->
  <div id="contentwrap">
    <div id="content">
  test<br>
    </div>
  </div><!--contentwrap-->
</div><!--wrap-->`

Comment: Sorry for the shoddy readability of my comments. I guess above should have been posted as answers for proper formatting. Still getting my bearings on stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you for putting effort into this Tim.

In regards to your last fiddle, the problem is again that #sidebar and .container takes on the 100% height of the containing element - which again does not take into account the "fluid" height of .content. So in your fiddle #sidebar and .container stays at 100% height of the viewport.